# What is the metric "Configuration" in Oracle Enterprise Manager Performance graphs mean?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When looking at the OEM performance graphs what does the "Configuration" Metric indicate?

Since the term configuration is so generic, it is difficult to find meaningful results from a search. I have tried the help pages within OEM as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can check all the wait events on this Oracle page:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/waitevents001.htm

> Configuration
>
> Waits caused by inadequate configuration of database or instance
>   resources (for example, undersized log file sizes, shared pool size)

Ocurrences of log file switch, write complete waits or log buffer space are labeled "Configuration" on EM. Just click on "configuration" to see a more detailed graph about this events.

[EDIT]: An additional note... I don't remember seeing any meaningful ocurrences of "Configuration" events on any of the databases I've managed. Which either means I'm pretty good at sizing, or that it usually isn't a problem at all. I'm prone to choose the second one ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am seeing this on an update statement. I have a bit more available memory on the server. I will try to allocate it to Oracle.

Comment: Drill down on the "Configuration" event and check what is the cause, that may or may not be a memory issue. You may need to increase log file size to reduce log switch.